# Converting similarity value into a dissimilarity value

Tags: similarity, mathematics

Suppose we have similarity values between some data point in the interval $[0, 1]$. How can I transform this similarity values into a dissimilarity values in the interval $[0, ∞]$?

Comment: Would simply taking the inverse work? This would give you values in the range 1 to infinity, so if you want the lower bound to be zero you can simply subtract 1.

Comment: I find it strange that you want to convert a normalized value to a non-normalized one. Why not just use the normalized dissimilarity $1-x$?

Answer (score 0):

You can use $-\ln x$ as transformation. It will map the interval $(0, 1]$ to the interval $[0, \infty)$.

As proposed in the comments it would be much easier to convert the normalized similarity value $x$ to a dissimilarity value by $1-x$.